# Formatting the specific element in the list in python

Tags: python, formatting, nested-lists

I am new to python.

I have a list like this:

```
LIST = [ ['A','B','23'], ['C','D','2'], ['E','F','11'] ]
```

I want to change it to below:

```
LIST2 = [ ['A','B',[23]] , ['C','D',[2]] , ['E','F',[11] ] ]
```

The 3rd element has to be changed as shown above.

I tried it but not able to avoid single quotes.

Help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a list comprehension to generate a new list where the third element in each list is converted to an integer:

```
l = [ ['A','B','23'], ['C','D','2'], ['E','F','11'] ]
o = [x[:2] + [[int(x[2])]] for x in l]

print(o)
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'B', [23]], ['C', 'D', [2]], ['E', 'F', [11]]]
```

Note that it's not a good idea to name variables the same as internal objects such as `list`, even if you do change the case.

Comment: Thanks Nick .. i need those crazy long brackets there.. I further use lambda operations on these

Comment: Appreciate your help.. finally it worked for me after long tries.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
LIST = [ ['A','B','23'], ['C','D','2'], ['E','F','11'] ]

LIST2 = [[*head, [int(tail)]] for *head, tail in LIST]

print(LIST2)
```

Prints:

```
[['A', 'B', [23]], ['C', 'D', [2]], ['E', 'F', [11]]]
```

Comment: Cool use of `*`

Comment: Thanks Andrej for your help but it some how breaks for syntax error for me   LIST2 = [[ *head , [int(tail)]] for *head, tail in LIST ]
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Asrar What version of Python are you using? If something old, then Nick's answer will surely work :)

Comment: I am on 2.7.5. But the issue is I need those long brackets included. appreciate your help.